# Custom items to "path" in console2

Tags: path, usb, portability, console2

I was wondering if its possible to add custom folders to [console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) app, when it starts.
What i mean is, i created a USB flash that always uses drive letter X, and i have custom apps there, that i need to add to system path, to use them in console2. But the problem is, that don't want to install all of the applications to each computer i connect my USB, nor do i want to add them to system path, since the path will be wrong, when i remove the usb from computer.

So basically, what i want is to create fully portable usb drive with all of the software in it, and i want it to be automatically added and available to console2, but not to the computers system path..

i hope i made my goal clear..

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem, but I'm not entirely sure from your wording. Since you mentioned that you have already created a static drive letter ( X:\ ) for your USB drive, then couldn't you just add the programs to your shell using the path from your USB like this:

http://puu.sh/5wCqW.png

If you're using a different computer every time, then you might have to change the static drive letter for your USB on the computer that you're working on at that moment so that it matches the one in your Console2 shell:

http://www.howtogeek.com/96298/assign-a-static-drive-letter-to-a-usb-drive-in-windows-7/

Comment: But can I create a shortcut for console, to add multiple items to it's shell? Co's,  when I tried to follow tutorials,  it didn't worked..

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help you.. If you're looking to add paths of your programs into Console2, then you have follow his guide here: http://robertcorvus.com/how-to-run-octave-in-console2/   He puts the Octave.exe into one of the tabs, but it should work for other .exe files as well. When you want to load another program, you just have to open another tab that you have previously set your .exe into.